# How to output HD Video for a photo slideshow to a TV for purposes of a giant photo frame

Tags: tv

Hi guys I am thinking about getting a 32 LED HD TV to serve as a big photo frame on the wall. But I need a small/discrete or wireless? way to output video to it, does anyone have ideas on how I can acheive this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of options. Most TVs nowadays have a USB port and can play media files from a USB flash drive. If you need streaming - there are more than a few sub $100 WIFI enabled media players which would qualify for "small/discrete". One of the most popular ones is [Roku](http://www.roku.com/roku-products).